# How to update Google Chrome after 32bit discontinuation?

Tags: chrome, software-updates

A few days ago I noticed this error message in the updates:

> ```
> Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
> ```

Actually, the solution was simple by adding `[arch=amd64]` after `deb`

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

in the file

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

But after every restart (I don't know a precise moment) it just disappears, any idea how to fix it for good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [webupd8_fix-failed-to-fetch](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html) (read the update), edit the following two files:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Change line #3 from:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

to:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Edit `/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome`

Change REPOCONFIG and SSLREPOCONFIG from:

```
REPOCONFIG="deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
SSLREPOCONFIG="deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
```

to:

```
REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
SSLREPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"
```